# Remotly wipe/lock the device using SyncAdapter : Android

Tags: android, synchronization

I am using sample code given in [SDK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html). In this demo I observe that DeviceAdmin also included in this sample.

It seems that we can handle device lock or device wipe functionality remotely.

So can you help me that how can I do this? Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is documentation on developer.google.com: [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Comment: I read this documentation. There no any way to how to do those task remotely. I have used DeviceAdmin in my sample app also.

Comment: If you have an installed application then you can simply include in your application methods for remote control: for instance, through C2DM or via SMS, MMS, Bluetooth and so on. The design is completely depends on you.

Comment: I have problem that how to send commands from 3rd Party server. Is it required to implement my own listener to handle those commands. How can I implement this?

Comment: You should read about push notifications (C2DM). And yes you should implement this by yourself.

Comment: Actually I am confused that when I will send a command from C2DM, my device will receive this, the is it necessary to implement a code that will read message and execute command? or is there any way that OS will handle commands automatically?

Comment: You should write this code by yourself. I do not think that there is a possibility to read the message by OS itself (it does not know the message and what to do with it).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a persistent TCP connection between your App and the server for two-way communication. You can then send commands over this connection. For some sample code you can take a look at the following thread:

[How can i lock the android device with a password programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761484/how-can-i-lock-the-android-device-with-a-password-programatically/9763009#9763009)

Comment: Can you provide the link for your full source code please?. Thank you.

Comment: If you mean link for the open source project, it is: svn checkout http://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ openmobster-read-only. Full Disclosure: I am the Chief Engineer for OpenMobster