# Programmatically changing ScreenLock mode from "Slide" to "Pattern" Android

Tags: android, locking, mode, screen-lock

I was able to implement locking and unlocking of Screen-Lock programmatically. But I was wondering if its possible to change the mode of Screen-Lock  say from 'slide' to 'pattern' or 'password' programmatically.

I searched the net but could'nt find anything, all results were about the usual locking and unlocking which I have already done.

Can any1 tell me if its possible ? If yes then how shall I achieve it.

Any help will be appreciated :) Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html). And [DeviceAdminSample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.java) is a good start.

There are following types you can set using [setPasswordQuality()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setPasswordQuality%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29)

```
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_NUMERIC,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHABETIC,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_ALPHANUMERIC,
        DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_COMPLEX
```

There are several answers on SO

- [How can i set up screen lock with a password programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724428/how-can-i-set-up-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically)
- [How can i lock the android device with a password programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761484/how-can-i-lock-the-android-device-with-a-password-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply :) But what if my default Sceen-Lock is 'Slide' one? Will it work then ? For Eg I usually open my phone by slide lock, but I want it to change to pattern lock or password lock from my app.

Comment: ok thanks I will try it out now. I believe I can do the same thing for pattern lock also, right ?

Comment: Yes you can. I think for that PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING is used.